# How to request additional data with WER?

Tags: minidump, windows-error-reporting, winqual

I'm new to WER (actually, just registered a few days ago).

I've managed to establish an account and map my test application to it.

However, when I invoke an unhandled exception, I see that no additional files are collected (there is proper report in Solutions center with BucketID <> 8, it is not arrived yet to winqual, but at least it was sent).

I expect that files like Version.txt, AppCompat.txt and minidump.mdmp will be collected. I also tried to add file by using [WerRegisterFile function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513619(VS.85).aspx). No errors, but no files are sent either.

I've read [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/isvwindowserrors/thread/1fa36bda-23cf-4dc4-ad7d-c62edf5dbb14/) - it says that additional data is only collected, if server asks for it. So, my question is (may be it sounds stupid, but...): *how can I request additional data?* I've scanned everything in my profile, but the only useful options are related to product/file mappings.

I feel that this should be obvious (it's not discussed in help), but... I'm stuck :( A screenshot indicating where to look would be nice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's strange that nobody have answered on that question, as the answer was a very simple :)

You can not collect any data for new errors. Error report should arrive on WinQual first. Then you can view a report (there is short info only) and ask server to collect files, dumps, additional info. Only then additional data will be collected.